# Как правильно написать регулярку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Добрый день, пишу роутер простенький.

В роутере прописываются несколько маршрутов поэтому следующий код выполняется через цикл который перебирает маршруты.

```
preg_match(Router::$_regex[$key],$uri, $result);
    var_dump($result);

    if( empty($result) )
        return false;
```

`Router::$_regex[$key]` находится регулярка - `|^test/id$|is`

Если человек вводит правильно урл (site.ru/test/id) то пропускаем его дальше.

Если регулярка другая то останавливаем этот круг в цикле и идем дальше проверять

А вот как сделать так что бы если человек ввел `site.ru/test/id/blabla/bla` то выводилась ошибка? У меня срабатывает `return false;` хотя он должен работать только во втором случае...

Comment: так в чем проблема ?

Если у вас нету подходящих регулярок (ни одна регулярка не подошла), значит такого адресса не существует и нужно показать ошибку.

Comment: Решение найдено.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю не нужен просто доллар, обозначающий конец строки

```
|^test/id|is
```